# How can i disable the update prompt?

Tags: updates, package-management, update-manager

How to disable the auto update dialog box shows every time while i am working? I have applied the following command yesterday but today still that is showing up. Is there any other way to permanently forever disable it?

```
$ gconftool -s --type bool /apps/update-notifier/auto_launch false
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the update manager, click the settings button in the bottom right.  In the `Updates` tab of the resulting window, there are a number of options that control the behaviour of the update manager.

What is annoying you is that the `When there are security updates:` setting is set to `Display Immediately`.  If you would like the protection of these security updates without being bothered, consider setting this to `Download and install automatically` instead.

With this change, the update manager will pop up at most once a week for the non-security updates.  You can switch this to fortnightly by changing `When there are other updates:` to `Display every two weeks`.

There is also an option to turn off checking for updates entirely in this tab, but I would recommend against picking it since it can leave your system vulnerable to preventable problems.

Comment: Can i also do this via command line? I have most of the time SSH access only.

Comment: Changing the security updates section updates the `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic` file, updating the `APT::Periodic::Download-Upgradeable-Packages` and `APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade` settings.

Comment: I don't think that this actually disables the update dialog. For instance after making this change, if you run `sudo apt update` (but not `upgrade`) the dialog will still pop-up again in the near future. This may have changed since the answer was posted, but I think @stsquad's answer is better.

Answer (score 2):

I also find this annoying as I use the command line to update my system on my netbook. One way to silence it is to remove the package:

```
apt-get remove update-manager-core
```

It will also remove ubuntu-desktop and the janitor packages but in my case (Gnome3) it makes no difference to the base system I'm using. I suspect you could also remove the notifier from the start-up applications but that requires making them visible to you in the first place.

Comment: Is it a recommended solution?

Answer (score 1):

### Ubuntu

---

Open Terminal. Type:

```
sudo sed -i "s/NoDisplay=true/NoDisplay=false/g" /etc/xdg/autostart/*.desktop
gnome-session-properties
```

When the "Startup Applications Preferences" window pops up, under "Additional startup programs:", scroll down to:

> Update Notifier
>
> Check for available updates automatically

On the left, disable the checkbox for "Update Notifier". Click "Close".

Source:

- How to disable the update manager in ubuntu 12.04:

  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1966228&p=11895545#post11895545

### Lubuntu

---

Open LXTerminal. Type:

```
sudo sed -i "s/NoDisplay=true/NoDisplay=false/g" /etc/xdg/autostart/*.desktop
lxsession-edit
```

When the "Desktop Session Settings" window pops up, in the "Automatically Started Applications" tab, under "Applications automatically started after entering desktop:", scroll down to:

> Update Notifier | Check for available updates automatically

On the left, disable the checkbox for "Update Notifier". Click "OK".

Answer (score 0):

As superuser, remove (or move to a different directory) the following files:

- /etc/cron.daily/update-notifier-common
- /etc/cron.weekly/update-notifier-common
- /etc/xdg/autostart/update-notifier
- /etc/update-motd.d/85-fwupd
- /etc/update-motd.d/90-updates-available
- /etc/update-motd.d/91-release-upgrade
- /etc/update-motd.d/95-hwe-eol

I suspect there are others that I haven't found yet, these files are really all over the file system.